# Simple Android app color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app where I haven't explicitly defined any colors.  The app looks different on my phone than it does on a few other phones around my office (the title bar at the top of the app on my phone is blue with white letters and on other phones it's gray with white letters).  How do I make them all the same?  Is it as simple as just explicitly setting the color in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply one of available themes to your application. You can do it `AndroidManifest.xml`, just use `android:theme` attribute:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` if you want dark theme or `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` if you want light theme.

If you use put this app in one of your `<activity>` tags, only corresponding activity will be styled, if you put it in `<application>` tag, style will be applied to the whole application.

Of course, you can define your own style in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_window</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>    
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here's the example of `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
        />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        />
```

In this example, `AppTheme2` will be applied only to `Activity1`, while `AppTheme` will be applied to all other activities.

Answer (score 0):

All the buttons, textviews and other UI elements not designed by you will change their aspect depending on the selected Theme. If you choose the default theme, all the GUI widgets will look different depending on the device manufacturer, the Android version, etc.

You can specify a concrete theme, such as Holo, with the problem that it won't work on Android versions prior to 3.0. You can keep the default theme for the old version, or otherwise you can use this website to generate all the Holo-style GUI elements yourself:

http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 0):

> the title bar at the top of the app on my phone is blue with white
>   letters and on other phones it's gray with white letters

This is the problem with the customized frameworks of some OEMs. They override the default android styles. I assume that the device with a blue title bar is a Samsung device with TouchWiz on it, right?

I order to have a consistent title bar you'll have to declare your own theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/title_bar</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/WindowTitle</item>    
</style>

<style name="WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#BB000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.75</item>
</style>
```

The original [title_bar](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/activity_title_bar.9.png) 9 patch.

---

This is the answer to your question. However in my opinion you should't use title bars, use the ActionBar instead. You can use ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatibility.